# Code to print directly to the printer ZEBRA TPL in 2844 of a web application on the client machine

Tags: javascript, c#, zebra-printers, printers

I have a problem in a system, I need to print directly from the application directly to the Zebra TLP 2844 printer, today we use a Java applet to do this, put in a near future will no longer be possible to use this.

I made the code below, put it only works on a machine or a LAN using C #.

```
string [] lines = {"I8, A, 001," "\ n"
    "Q216,024"
    "Q831"
    "RN"
    "S3"
    "D7"
    "ZT"
    "JF"
    "OD"
    "R215,0"
    "F100"
    "C"
    "A388,49,1,3,1,1, N \" 09/04/2015 "\",
    "A322,74,0,1,1,1 N, \" 2 \ ""
    "A360,63,1,2,1,1 N, \" 002049765 \ ""
    "A215,146,0,2,1,1, N \" NTO \ ""
    "A304,152,0,1,1,1, N \" CRT \ ""
    "A67,176,0,1,1,1, N, \" TEST JUNIOR \ ""
    "A67,188,0,1,1,1, N \" NIQUE \ ""
    "A276,130,0,1,1,1, N \" TTRACE \ ""
    "A46,42,1,4,1,1, N \" 10-000029 "\",
    "B72,32,0,1,2,6,71, B, \" 100340356701 \ ""
    "A292,46,0,1,1,1, N \" SERUM \ ""
    "P9"
};

System.IO.File.WriteAllLines (@ "C: \ ETIQUETA.prn" lines);
System.IO.File.Copy ("c: \\ ETIQUETA.prn", "127.0.0.1 \\\\ zebradb \\");
```

I would like to help to make a code to do this server printer command directly to the client machine. Using any tool other than Java.

Thank you.

Comment: To start, this isn't valid code.  Nor is it javascript

Comment: This code is in C#, it creates a txt file and sends it to the printer.But this form only works for local applications, I would like to know a way to do this for a web application. Accessing the client printer. I believe this could be done in JavaScript or other web tool.

Answer (score 0):

This code is in C#, it creates a txt file and sends it to the printer.But this form only works for local applications, I would like to know a way to do this for a web application. Accessing the client printer. I believe this could be done in JavaScript or other web tool. –